# can't make sure only one instance is created in singleton pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I am trying to create a class which can be instantiate once.

```
$ins1,$ins4,$ins3
```

are created in such a way that if a static variable $instance is already defined it will be returned again and again.

```
$ins1==$ins4 returns true
```

instances `$ins4,$ins5` are created with `new` keyword.When i use

`$ins4==$ins5`

it also returned **ture**.**How can i be sure that only one instance is created**

```
<?php
class Singleton{

     private static $instance;

       public static function getInstance(){

            if(!self::$instance){
                echo " I AM THE FIRST INSTANCE and i am not from bypass<br>";
                self::$instance = new Singleton();
                return self::$instance;
            }else{
                echo "i am from bypass<br>";
                return self::$instance;
            }
       }

}

$ins1 = Singleton::getInstance();
$ins2 = Singleton::getInstance();
echo $ins1==$ins2;
echo '<br>';
$ins3 = Singleton::getInstance();

$ins4 = new Singleton();
$ins5 = new Singleton();

echo $ins4 == $ins5;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the constructor `protected` or `private`, otherwise anyone can invoke it:

```
class Singleton {
    protected __construct() {}

    public static getInstance() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Having said that, enforcing singletons like this is rarely a good idea. The better idea would be to simply instantiate the class only once and pass it around as needed through dependency injection; a dependency injection container which manages the instantiation and passing is helpful here.